# [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil' - Image

Tags: ios, image, uiimage, load, save

I'm working on a mini game.

In the game, the user can choose the own pictures, and use them in the game.

It's working fine, when I choose the picture, and save them to the app.

But when I load the picture into the game, I get this Error

```
 [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
```

I think it's because the app cannot find the picture. But I cannot see why. :-D

Yes I am a newbie with Xcode :-D

my code look like this

```
- (void)loadCellImages 
{
    [self unloadCellImages];
    for (int i=1;i<(totalcolors+1);i++) 
    {
        imageSaveLoad *imgSL = [[imageSaveLoad alloc] init];     
        [cellImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d",[imgSL loadImage:@"Photo-"],i] ofType:@"png"]]];
    }
}
```

and I load and save the picture from this:

### imageSaveLoad.m

```
//saving an image
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image forKey:(NSString*)imageName
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];

    NSLog(@"image saved %@",imageName);
}

//removing an image
- (void)removeImage:(NSString*)fileName
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", fileName]];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"image removed");
}

//loading an image
- (UIImage*)loadImage:(NSString*)imageName
{
   // NSLog(@"load %@",imageName);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]];
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];

}
```

Comment: From your description, it is hard to help you: In which line did you get the error message? If you don't know the line, set an exception breakpoint (in the Xcode breakpoint navigator, click the + at the bottom left, and enable it), and you app will stop where the error occurs. It should then be possible to find out why the object that you want to store in the NSMUtableArray is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving images to the `NSDocumentDirectory` but trying to load from your main bundle:

```
[cellImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d",[imgSL loadImage:@"Photo-"],i] ofType:@"png"]]];
```

You probably just want:

```
[cellImages addObject:[imgSL loadImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photo-", i]]];
```

You use the `mainBundle` for images (and resources) bundled with your app.

EDIT:
To make sure your images are being saved correctly, you should also check the return `BOOL` of [`createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createFileAtPath%3acontents%3aattributes%3a).

Comment: YEAH, you just saved my day, now its work with [cellImages addObject:[imgSL loadImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photo-", i]]]; I have got to learn :-D